# ESLINT: Linting inside comments block spaces/tab

Tags: javascript, eslint, lint

Is there a rule to check for multiple spaces or tabs inside a comment block in eslint?

```
 /**
 * Some jsdocs for a function
 * @param   {String}   argument string - string
 * @param   {Object}   property        - property object
 * @returns {Function} callback        - callback
 */
```

My desired output after `--fix` flag

```
 /**
 * Some jsdocs for a function
 * @param {String} argument string - string
 * @param {Object} property - property object
 * @returns {Function} callback - callback
 */
```